# Uninstalling Ubuntu completely

Tags: boot, windows-10, bootloader

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop, played around it for a bit, and then completely wiped the HDD. By completely, I mean that I literally wiped every partition merged and then formatted it again and then installed Windows 10.

**So my situation is:**
After all of this, I ran windows and all, but one day I went to the *Windows Boot Manager* and I saw the generic names like ATA HDD, ATAPI CD...And the last one was Ubuntu.

I tried clicking it, but it booted to Windows after that, and I wanted to install *Windows 7*. Then I realized that I couldn't boot from USB. I don't know if this was related, but I am just telling, for the sake of context.

**So my question now is:**
How can I remove the *Ubuntu* entry from the *Windows Boot Manager*?